# It seems there is a RN network inspector tool. Where?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

According to the documention,  there is a RN network inspector tool, and "XMLHttpRequest, Fetch and WebSocket are all supported.".  Does it works like whireshark or Charles? So I can see the Requests and responses within this tool?

the documention's link:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/43f73f675fd3f02b004b40e2b910ba4d7a52ea7f

Answer (score 2):

You first need to access the [in-app developer menu](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#accessing-the-in-app-developer-menu) and press Show Inspector.

[image: in app developer menu]

Once the inspector is opened, press the network tab and it will start logging the network activity.

[image]